# How to load css file dynamically

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

We are using **Vue.js** and **Vuetify** for my application. As part of my application, I will make API call on page load based on that API response entire application will render all the components. As part of this API, I will get property named as *cssDirection* and it tells which css file suppose to load either it's LTR or RTL.

When I worked in Angular, We used [this](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2011/03/20/link-tag-css-stylesheet-load-event/) approach.

Now my question is there any workaround to achieve this in Vue instead of the above approach ? I googled I didn't find any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

To load css file dynamically you can do somethings like this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="appendFile">Click me to add css file</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods : {
    appendFile(){
      let file = document.createElement('link');
      file.rel = 'stylesheet';
      file.href = 'myfile.css'
      document.head.appendChild(file)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Injecting a `<link>` into the page also works in vue, an alternative is to use webpack's code splitting.

```
if (data.rtl) {
  import("./css/rtl.css")
} else {
  import("./css/ltr.css")
}
```

Comment: Does it work with loading CSS file from an external source like a CDN?

Comment: Not out of the box, there are plugins for that https://openbase.io/js/webpack-external-import but unless it happens frequently in your codebase i'd suggest adding it manually to the dom like the other answer suggest

Answer (score 3):

Use `import("")` to load the static css from assets, for example if are you using multiple files for styling:

On App.vue:

```js
<script setup>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { computed, watchEffect } from "@vue/runtime-core";

const store = useStore();
const theme = computed(() => store.state.theme);

watchEffect(() => {
  import(`./assets/css/themes/${theme.value}.css`);
});
<script/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import(path);
in lifecycle
```

And set your file name dynamically in data, for example:

```
data(){
   return{
      filename: 'test1',
   }
}
created(){
import(`./assets/css/themes/${this.filename}.css`);
}
```