# How to import internal css conditionally with javascript vuejs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Currently, I have to import css file conditionally depend on which kind of browser users are using. To not making css file global, I have the following code:

```
  created() {
      this.checkIsMobile()
  },
  methods: {
      checkIsMobile(){
        var isMobile = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
        if (isMobile.mobile()){
          $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@/assets/css/main-pc.css">');
        }else {
          $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@/assets/css/main-m.css">'); //must be load external css
        }
      },
```

It does not work because it's internal css.

I can not import in style tag because there are some link to other images in my css. Importing in style will lead to `relative modules were not found`

How should I do with without uploading css file to somewhere?

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767025/how-to-load-css-file-dynamically) is theoretically the same as what I just did (without jQuery)

Comment: Why is there jQuery in your VueJS app? For your VueJS app, are you using a bundler like webpack? If you are, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52769714/395910

Comment: Why not just statically include a single CSS file and use media queries to override different rules for smaller screen sizes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load css file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767025/how-to-load-css-file-dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuejs compiles in a different way, so import or adding internal css file to head does not work. Simply use `require`:

```
    if (isMobile.mobile()){
      require('@/assets/css/mobile.css');
    }else {
      require('@/assets/css/pc.css');
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the above technique and it works wonderfully in DEV. However upon migrating to PROD it seems as though *both* .css files are compiled. This results in the 'wrong' css styles being applied. Thoughts?

Comment: @dbaron I think it depends on the method you used to compile css files. Usually it will have its own function to load compiled files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following method?

```
<style scoped>
@import './../file.css';
</style>
```

Source URL: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-import-css-files-into-single-file-component/41337

Comment: I can't use this with condition

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use JQuery. It is slow, big size and everything that you using jquery you can do in Vue.

Second, you shouldn't detect screen size in JS, but in CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I used this library https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js to detect screen size, seems reliable. Detecting mobile using CSS might be the answer, but it break my work flow