# Dynamically use css files with vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

We are working with Vue and the client has asked us for a button that allows him to choose the theme that he prefers.

The point is, I need to dynamically load the css file that corresponds to each theme.

I have tried this: [How to load css file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767025/how-to-load-css-file-dynamically)
but I haven't made it work.

My code:

Account.vue:

```
multiselect(
           v-model="theme",
           :placeholder="$t('Select')",
           label="name",
           track-by="code",
           :showLabels="false"
           :options="themes",
           :multiple="false",
           :taggable="false",
           :selectLabel="$t('SelectLabel')",
    .columns
      .column.has-text-centered
         button.button(@click='sendData, appendFile', :disabled="!language || !rol || !theme") {{ $t('Save') }}
```

JS:

```
data() {
    return {
      theme: null,
      themes: [
        { name: 'Default', code: 'def' },
        { name: 'Montich', code: 'mont' },
      ],
    };
  },

methods: {
    sendData() {
       this.$store.dispatch('THEME_SELECT', this.theme.code).then(() => {
      });
    appendFile() {
      const file = document.createElement('link');
      file.rel = 'stylesheet';
      file.href = 'assets/css/montich.css';
      file.head.appendChild(file);
    },
  },
```

Now some prints:
[...Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLFtd.png)
[...Network and view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGEhI.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not change the class of the button when the state theme changes? For example, you can switch the class between button--default and button--montich . You don't need to load css files dynamically. That's not a good way to create components.

Comment: Hi @ThetAung Well, I thought the same and that is what I proposed to my leader (I am a trainee and my first working week as a web dev has just finished), and he told me that since there are many clients who will have different themes, it would be less than optimal load all styles on a single css sheet. So he asked that each theme be loaded on a different style sheet ...

Comment: You should tell him that when the user tries to change to a different theme requesting another css file from server (which you're trying to do) is not a good practice. It's be much slower than adding a few line of css code for each theme even if there's 100 of them. Any library that creates components never do that.

Comment: You might be interested in this https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/dark-light-switch-css-javascript

Comment: Thank you @ThetAung! I'll keep your advice in mind and i'll talk to my leader about your proposal. 

Of course im going to check your link right now. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @ThetAung! Sorry but I wanted to ask you if you could send me an example of your first solution. I've been struggling with it and I would appreciate if you help me a bit with it.

It would be great for me if I show my TL some results so he finally decides to advance with that solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll give you codesandbox link. You might have to wait for a while. It'll take some time.

Comment: here you go. https://codesandbox.io/s/btnthemechangeexample-ouxev . 
I used the button from the project I'm currenly working on, so, I'm sorry if it's hard to understand. But feel free to ask me anything. I just used scss instead of css. Other than that everthing should be easy to understand.

Comment: If you check scss code of the component, you can see that the difference between different theme is only a few line of code. So, no point in requesting another css file from the server.

Comment: @ThetAung dude you're one of a kind. I truly appreciate what you did and the time you invested on trying to learn me some stuff I was not used to. It really helped me to finally make it works and I just did, so I just wanted to say thanks and I hope to learn as much as you to help people in situations like mine in the future. Bye!

Comment: It's my pleasure. And I wish you good luck.